# MySQLでPDOのエラー時にロールバックされない

Tags: php, mysql

Laravel5.0で行数の多いCSVファイルの内容を MySQL の「LOAD DATA local INFILE 〜」コマンドを使ってデータベースを書き換えようとしています。
既存の内容を新しい内容で完全に置き換えるので、一旦内容を truncate してから書き込むようにしていますが、タイムアウトなどで処理が中断されてしまった場合はロールバックさせるために次のようにしました。（$destination にはファイルの場所が格納されています。）

```
$query = sprintf("LOAD DATA local INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE `zip_codes` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  IGNORE 0 LINES (`zip`, `address1`, `address2`, `address3`)", addslashes($destination));

$pdo = DB::connection()->getpdo();
$pdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `zip_codes`");
    $pdo->exec($query);
    $pdo->commit();
}catch(\PDOException $e){
    $pdo->rollBack();
}
```

わざと存在しないファイル名を指定すると catch 部分は実行されているようですが内容は truncate で消去された状態のままでした。

専用の DB::transaction() や、DB::beginTransaction()、DB::rollback() を使ってみても catch 処理が行われる前にフレームワーク側で catch されてしまっているようで同じような結果になりました。

このような場合どのようにしてロールバック処理を行えばいいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 補足: エンジンはInnoDBです。

Comment: MySQLのtrancateがロールバックの対象ではないと思いますので、Laravelの問題ではないかと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

（コメントに書いていましたが、Whoopsに関する記述が削除されたようなので回答にします）

MySQL では TRUNCATE 時に自動でコミットが行われます。したがってTRUNCATE自体はもちろん、それ以前に行った操作も、TRUNCATE後にロールバックすることはできません。

- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 13.1.29 TRUNCATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html)
- [TRUNCATE (SQL) - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRUNCATE_(SQL))

なお、PHPの [`set_exception_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/ja/function.set-exception-handler.php) では例外**発生時**にハンドリングすることはできませんから、通常そのようなことはないと考えてよいと思います。

> 例外が try/catch ブロックの中でキャッチされなかった場合の デフォルトの例外ハンドラを設定します。 例外は、exception_handler がコールされた後に 停止します。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。MySQL自体の正常な仕様なのですね。DELETEに変えて対応することでロールバックすることが出来ました。

Answer (score 5):

MySQLでは`TRUNCATE`はRollbackできないみたいです。
`DELETE`を使うとRollbackできます。

参考サイト
http://www.sria.co.jp/blog/2014/08/mysql-can-do-rollback-truncate/

Comment: RDBMSの種類によってTRUNCATEがトランザクション対象がどうかが異なるのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 3):

ファイルが存在しない時は、PDOException以外のExceptionが上がってきているかも知れません。まずは、Exceptionクラスをハンドリングしてチェックしてみては？

```
try {
    $pdo->beginTransaction();
    $pdo->exec("TRUNCATE TABLE `zip_codes`");
    $pdo->exec($query);
} catch (\PDOException $e) {
    dd(get_class($e));

    $pdo->rollBack();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    dd(get_class($e));
}
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。上記コードの結果は「"PDOException"」でした。「\Exception」だけ残してcatchしてみても同じだったので今のところPDOException以外は発生していないようですね。